# Why is html text not changing after detecting website language?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a banner for an AB testing. The problem is that my code has to recognize the languague on the pace (English or french) and change to the right languague:

I have created the following function but it is not working.

```
var lang = document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang'),
 title = '',
 subtitle = '',
 ctaText = '';

 if (lang === 'en-be') {
        title = 'Collect points everyday and redeem them for rewards!';
        subtitle = 'Choose an activity below to start earning points or if you already have them, redeem now!';
        ctaText = "GO TO REWARDS >";
        init();
    } else if (lang === 'fr-be') {
        title = 'Accumulez des points tous les jours et échangez-les contre des récompenses!';
        subtitle = 'Choisissez une des activités ci-dessous pour commencer à accumuler des points. Si vous en avez déjà, échangez-les dès maintenant!';
        ctaText = "VOIR LES RÉCOMPENSES >";
        init();
    }


    var croContent = ` 
    <div class="cro-abtest">
        <div class="cro-banner">
            <div>
                <div>` + title + `</div>
                <div>` + subtitle + `</div>
            </div>
        <img src="https://admin.jtidrive.ca/cms/media/620ba1d7669ff63d900ae5a6.png">
        <div>
            <img src="https://admin.jtidrive.ca/cms/media/620ba1da669ff63d900ae5a7.png">
            <a href="https://rewards.jtidrive.ca/"  onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'cro-banner', 'click', 'cro-rewards');">` + ctaText + `</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    `;

var croCA = document.querySelector("#root > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3)");
croCA.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', croContent);

var croCSS = '<style> .cro-abtest {max-width: 1280px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;} .cro-banner {display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:center;align-items: center;border: 1px solid #707070;margin:25px 0px;font-family:Roboto;padding: 25px;} .cro-banner > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) {color: #0EB0A7;font-weight:500;font-size: 1.875rem;} .cro-banner > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) {color: #888888;} .cro-abtest > div > img:nth-child(2){width:40rem;;height: 10rem;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(3) > img {display:none;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(3) > a {background: #0EB0A7;padding: 5px 10px;border-radius: 1px;color: white;white-space: nowrap;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(1) {width:25rem;} @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {.cro-abtest > div > img{width:30rem;;height: 7rem;} .cro-banner > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) {font-size: 1.125rem;}}  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {.cro-banner{flex-direction: column;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(1) {width:100%;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(3) {display:flex;align-items:center;}.cro-abtest > div > img:nth-child(2) {display:none;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(3) > img{display: block;width: 176px;height: 82px;}}</style>'
croCA.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', croCSS);
```

When the user in their account has english, the function has to recognize document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang') as english and add the english text but if the account has french in is configuration it should be replaced by the french text

Anyone knows where i am mistaken?

Comment: So what is the result? does it just don't work? or just show the `en` language stuff?

Comment: When the user in their account has english, the function has to recognize document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang') as english and add the english text but if the account has french in is configuration it should be replaced by the french text. When use gtattribute it works recogize it is french or english but does not replace the text

Comment: So if the recognization part is ok and works fine as you tested it might be the selector `#root > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3)` maybe the selector is not ok. try to run `document.querySelector("#root > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3)");` in the developer tools of browser and make sure it works fine.

Comment: I am gonna try..right now it gives me an empty banner with no text. The problem is that it is not filling the div with texts..it is empty now

Comment: Did you try `document.querySelector("#root > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3)");` in browser developer tools console? can you share you html as well?

Comment: Yes, the selector works fine. I can see the banner where I want to see it. The problem is that the the text does not show up

Comment: Can you share some HTML. What is the value in <html lang="?">

Comment: It didnt work because i was using 'en-be' and it was en-ca

Comment: @MiguelBastidasMoreno are you familiar with choosing or upvoting the right answer or comment?

Comment: No, i am new with stackoverflow..very junior

Comment: Click the check-mark left of the answer or click the up arrow also to the left of the answer or comment to upvote. [Look at this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361928/how-do-i-select-the-best-answer)

Comment: it says Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Without you posting the HTML i created a simple html and it's working for me:

```
<html lang="en-be">
<head>
  <title>demo</title>
  <script>
    function banner() {
      var lang = document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang'),
      title = '',
      subtitle = '',
      ctaText = '';
      if (lang === 'en-be') {
        title = 'Collect points everyday and redeem them for rewards!';
        subtitle = 'Choose an activity below to start earning points or if you already have them, redeem now!';
        ctaText = "GO TO REWARDS >";
      } else if (lang === 'fr-be') {
        title = 'Accumulez des points tous les jours et échangez-les contre des récompenses!';
        subtitle = 'Choisissez une des activités ci-dessous pour commencer à accumuler des points. Si vous en avez déjà, échangez-les dès maintenant!';
        ctaText = "VOIR LES RÉCOMPENSES >";       
      }
      var croContent = ` 
      <div class="cro-abtest">
        <div class="cro-banner">
            <div>
                <div>` + title + `</div>
                <div>` + subtitle + `</div>
            </div>
        <img src="https://admin.jtidrive.ca/cms/media/620ba1d7669ff63d900ae5a6.png">
        <div>
            <img src="https://admin.jtidrive.ca/cms/media/620ba1da669ff63d900ae5a7.png">
            <a href="https://rewards.jtidrive.ca/"  onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'cro-banner', 'click', 'cro-rewards');">` + ctaText + `</a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      `;

      var croCA = document.querySelector("p");
      croCA.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', croContent);
      var croCSS = '<style> .cro-abtest {max-width: 1280px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;} .cro-banner {display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:center;align-items: center;border: 1px solid #707070;margin:25px 0px;font-family:Roboto;padding: 25px;} .cro-banner > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) {color: #0EB0A7;font-weight:500;font-size: 1.875rem;} .cro-banner > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) {color: #888888;} .cro-abtest > div > img:nth-child(2){width:40rem;;height: 10rem;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(3) > img {display:none;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(3) > a {background: #0EB0A7;padding: 5px 10px;border-radius: 1px;color: white;white-space: nowrap;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(1) {width:25rem;} @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {.cro-abtest > div > img{width:30rem;;height: 7rem;} .cro-banner > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) {font-size: 1.125rem;}}  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {.cro-banner{flex-direction: column;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(1) {width:100%;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(3) {display:flex;align-items:center;}.cro-abtest > div > img:nth-child(2) {display:none;} .cro-abtest > div > div:nth-child(3) > img{display: block;width: 176px;height: 82px;}}</style>'
      croCA.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', croCSS);
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="banner();">
  <p>placeholder.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Below are the generated banners respectively for english and french:
[image: English Banner] 
[image: French Banner]
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj39mLbt/)

Comment: thank you. this is very helpful. the problem is that I was using the wrong language code...it was not  'en-be' it was en-ca

Comment: @MiguelBastidasMoreno You can look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361928/how-do-i-select-the-best-answer)